# How to make build definitions more organized?

Tags: build, tfs, categories

I met a problem about build definition.

Now there are almost 50 Gated build definiton.

Every sprint we will create a branch after we release a version.

We still want to add the GATED mechnism on branch, So there will be >100 build definitions in the list.

It is too many build definitions.

Is there a may to make some folders and put them in different categories(trunk , branchs) in the list?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what version of TFS you are using.

For TFS 2010, there's an addon you can install called [Inmeta.VisualStudio.TeamExplorer.BuildExplorer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/35daa606-4917-43c4-98ab-38632d9dbd45). It allows you to "build" a treeview of your build definitions based on a chosen separator character (default is ".").

I haven't seen anything like that for TFS 2012, but in there you can select favorite build definitions, and also filter the list of definitions.

Comment: 2012 has a search function for builds which also helps makes it more manageable.